# finding minimum number of jumps

Tags: c++, algorithm

Working on below algorithm puzzle of finding minimum number of jumps. Posted detailed problem statement and two code versions to resolve this issue. I have did testing and it seems both version works, and my 2nd version is an optimized version of version one code, which makes i starts from `i=maxIndex`, other than continuous increase, which could save time by not iteration all the slots of the array.

My question is, wondering if my 2nd version code is 100% correct? If anyone found any logical issues, appreciate for pointing out.

**Problem Statement**

Given an array of non-negative integers, you are initially positioned at the first index of the array.

Each element in the array represents your maximum jump length at that position.

Your goal is to reach the last index in the minimum number of jumps.

For example:
Given array A = [2,3,1,1,4]

The minimum number of jumps to reach the last index is 2. (Jump 1 step from index 0 to 1, then 3 steps to the last index.)

**First version code**

```
class Solution {
public:
    int jump(vector<int>& nums) {
        int i = 0, n = nums.size(), step = 0, end = 0, maxend = 0;
        while (end < n - 1) {
            step++;
            for (;i <= end; i++) {
                maxend = max(maxend, i + nums[i]);
                if (maxend >= n - 1) return step;
            }
            if(end == maxend) break;
            end = maxend;
        }
        return n == 1 ? 0 : -1;
    }
};
```

**2nd version code**

```
class Solution {
public:
    int jump(vector<int>& nums) {
        int i = 0, n = nums.size(), step = 0, end = 0, maxend = 0;
        int maxIndex = 0;
        while (end < n - 1) {
            step++;
            for (i=maxIndex;i <= end; i++) {
                if ((i + nums[i]) > maxend)
                {
                  maxend = i + nums[i];
                  maxIndex = i;
                }

                if (maxend >= n - 1) return step;
            }
            if(end == maxend) break;
            end = maxend;
        }
        return n == 1 ? 0 : -1;
    }
};
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Here's a tip on how you can make this problem more tractable, and therefore more likely other will help:
Show us the recurrence relation that makes up your solution, and then the code that's supposed to do it. This way, we can reason about it, rather than play spot the difference on procedural code.
Lastly,  can you jump up to nums[i] to the right, or only exactly nums[i] right?

Comment: They both give the same answer every time it's run, so I assume it works.

Comment: @JamesRoot, with your confirmation, I am more confident. If you could make an answer, I will mark it as an Answer so that benefit other people as well. :)

Comment: @TomaszKaminski, we can definitely jump beyond right, which is a valid jump. But I think it does not impact the result, correct? Thanks.

Comment: @TomaszKaminski, I think I have clarified why and what are my optimized 2nd version of code, here it is, "my 2nd version is an optimized version of version one code, which makes i starts from i=maxIndex, other than continuous increase, which could save time by not iteration all the slots of the array", and wondering what do you mean "recurrence relation"? -- do you mean I should clarify why and what optimizations I did? Thanks.

Comment: @linma I think the answer should logically prove it works, or offer an improvement. I just wrote a loop and called a function in it.

Comment: @JamesRoot, thanks for the response. Do you mean my improvement code is correct, or not? Sorry a bit miss your conclusion. :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is always to test it. A human cannot always think about special cases but a automated test can cover the most of speciale cases. If you think that your first version works well, you can compare the result of the first with the second one. Here an exemple:

```
/*
 * arraySize    : array size to use for the test
 * min          : min jump in the array
 * max          : max jump in the array
 */
void testJumps(int arraySize, int min, int max){

    static int counter = 0;
    std::cout << "-----------Test " << counter << "------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Array size : " << arraySize << "   Minimum Jump : " << min << "   Max Jump" << max << std::endl; 
    //Create vector with random numbers
    std::vector<int> vecNumbers(arraySize, 0);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vecNumbers.size(); i++)
        vecNumbers[i] = rand() % max + min;

    //Value of first function
    int iVersion1 = jump1(vecNumbers);

    //Second fucntion
    int iVersion2 = jump2(vecNumbers);

    assert(iVersion1 == iVersion2);

    std::cout << "Test " << counter << " succeeded" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-----------------------" << std::endl;

    counter++;

}

int main()
{
    //Two test
    testJumps(10, 1, 100);
    testJumps(20, 10, 200);

    //You can even make a loop of test
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Captain, I have tested already and not found any issues. But I am not 100% confident so I come here for help. Wondering if you have any good thoughts or finding any issues yet?